# treating errors in android http connection

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-asynctask

I have a class responsible for sending JSON to the server, this class extends AsyncTask. But I can not handle errors of connection. If the device does not have connection with the internet app is terminated, and if the app is in flight mode is also terminated. how to handle these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these method:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Call this before you start the asyncTask for data pull. This will check if the device has a connection to the internet. Also don't forget to add permissions on your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Excellent this code. will help me with my problem. thank you very much